# sending mail with attachement using Amazon SDK php

Tags: amazon-web-services

Anyone does know if it's possible to send attachments with the method sendEmail without build the message manually?

actually i send this parameters, but I find no docs for attachs files:

```
 $message = array(
        'Source' => $this->sender,
        'Destination' => array(
            'ToAddresses' => [$this->to],
        ),
        'Message' => array(
            'Subject' => array(
                'Data' => $this->subject,
                'Charset' => 'utf-8',
            ),
            'Body' => array(
                'Text' => array(
                    'Data' => $this->bodytext,
                    'Charset' => 'utf-8',
                ),
                'Html' => array(
                    // Data is required
                    'Data' => $this->bodyhtml,
                    'Charset' => 'utf-8',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aws: ses with attach files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829198/aws-ses-with-attach-files)

Comment: duplicate solve the problem in a manual way, i've completed the right solution in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the best easy way to send attach files it's use phpmailer to compose the body including the attach files and send it in Amazon through the .SendRawEmail method