# Amazon SES send email with attachemnt in codeingiter

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter-3, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email with attachment using **Amazon SES**.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<?php
$file_path = DOC_ROOT.'/report/';
$myfile    = $file_path.$filename;
$file_size = filesize($myfile);
$handle    = fopen($myfile, "r");
$content   = fread($handle, $file_size);

$subject = 'Report';
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$header  = "";

$message = 
  '<html>
        <head><title></title></head>
        <body>
            <p>Hello '.$vEmail.',</p></br>
            <p>Please find attached file.</p>    
            <p>Regards,</p>
            <p>'.MAINTITLE.'</p></br>
        </body>
        </html>';  

$ses = new Simpleemailservice(AWS_ACCESSKEY, AWS_SECRET);
$from = FROM_EMAIL_SES;    
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: ".$from." <".$from.">\r\n";
$header .= "To: ".$vEmail."\r\n";
$header .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/csv; name=\"".$myfile."\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$myfile."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";

$msg['RawMessage']['Data'] = base64_encode($header);
$msg['RawMessage']['Source']= $from;
$msg['RawMessage']['Destinations'] = $vEmail;
fclose($handle);

$result = $ses->sendRawEmail($msg);
$msg_id = $result->get('MessageId');
?>
```

the error I am getting:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `setParameter()` on a non-object
>   in `/libraries/Simpleemailservice.php` on line 267

I found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829198/aws-ses-with-attach-files/24487637#comment73960073_24487637) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there could be a problem with initialization,
You can check the API documentation for details.

I can give you a better option with PHPMailer and Amazon SNS.You can check out the code that I gave below.
https://gist.github.com/kilitbilgi/f697898339e3e751c32c735ac9c4ba1d

Comment: It can be the problem with your credential sir, can you check your API, SECRET key and your region.

Comment: I also update my gist file and add example function call